# Google App Engine And Restlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I've been tinkering with this [sample](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html#dsy303-restlet_common-classes) trying to determine if restlet will work with Google app engine to meet my needs.  It seems fairly straight forward so far but I've been stuck on something for a couple of hours now and would appreciate some help...

Client code

```
 ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("my_gae_url");
 ContactResource resource = cr.wrap(ContactResource.class);
```

This returns a null

```
 Contact contact = resource.retrieve()
```

but this returns the expected json string

```
 String s = cr.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).getText();
```

It won't return the object but it will return the json.  I don't know if I'm missing a jar or I haven't implemented something or what

```
 I'm using Google Plugin 3.7 and app engine 1.7.2
 I'm using restlet app engine edition 2.0.15 
 The server includes the following jars org.restlet.jar, org.restlet.ext.gwt.jar,           
 org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar, org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar,
 org.codehaus.jackson.core.jar, org.codehaus.jackson.mapper.jar
```

If it matters the client i'm using to test things out is jsf with the following jars included

```
 org.restlet.jar, org.restlet.ext.net.jar
```

Comment: You need to add Jackson extension on the client side as well

Comment: The jackson extension did the trick.  Thanks a bunch!  Now if someone could tell me how to mark a comment as the answer

Comment: Cool. Reentered comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Jackson extension on the client side as well